# Is there a way to "Refresh" Captcha?

Tags: captcha

Is there a way to refresh the Captacha value without having to reload the page? If so, how?

Comment: Hi fmz, did the below answer your question? If so please mark the answer to help other site users. If not please do share the

Comment: Hi fmz, did the below answer your quesrtion? It's good form to mark the answer if it worked for you, as it helps others faced with the same issue! If you're still stuck, please do comment or edit your OP and let us know your challange and we'lldo all we can to help you out!!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use some ajax and create an endpoint, ergo refreshing just the captcha.

Fortunatly, once you have that in place actually creating a captcha is totally easy, there's a helper in the system but the function is also available via ee itself :

```
//create a captcha and return the HTML
$captchaHtml = ee()->functions->create_captcha();
```

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/functions.html#create-captcha